# Wordpress using str_replace

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

How can I replace the content of an existing tag using str_replace in functions.php?

For example, the DOM displays

```
<h1> smth </h1>
```

and I would like to change it to

```
<h2> smth else </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newString = str_replace('h1', 'h2', '<h1> smth </h1>');
$newString = str_replace('smth', 'smth else', $newString);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php